# Using AND and OR in the same Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND active='1' OR reserved='1'";
```

I want to pull all users where Active or Reserved = 1 but I don't think I'm doing it correct.

Comment: Use parentheses around  `active='1' OR reserved='1'"`

Comment: I hope your cleaning those SQL query before being executed.

Comment: Why are people downvoting? I don't even see any explanatory comments..

Comment: @asifrc the community somehow allow new users to down vote like crazy or people down vote new users to prevent them from getting rep, I think its a new form of trolling.

Comment: @Musk Take the tin foil hat off. It takes one upvote on an answer to counter 5 downvotes and one upvote on a question to counter 2.5 downvotes. Whatever reason people are downvoting, it's not to keep new users from getting rep. I don't even understand why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: @asifrc Because people think it's easy for beginners to do a Google search or Stack Overflow search for something concerning `and` or `or`, when they usually get ignored as operators for the search engine query.  Also, this community is against beginners.

Comment: @Juhana I was just offering a simple analysis most new user I encounter who posted most of the time clear to the point question were down voted. And high rep people offering clear advise to new users were down voted. Silly how it is, maybe they are just reading to quick and aren't understanding, hell God know's.

Comment: Akam answered my question almost immediately after it was asked.  I don't understand why there is a need for clarification as I was simply asking how to perform both in the same query, that is all.

Comment: To avoid the risk of a blog-like comment I'll make this as short as possible. @Juhana Given that someone has posted a question on SO because there is something they don't understand, it's unlikely that they'll figure out what's wrong with how they posed their question in addition to having their question less likely to be answered by the community by those who do understand it. (i.e it just makes someone who's confused about something even more confused.) It's one of the most destructive things for the SO community. We shouldn't simply expect our new users to be 'better', we should teach them.

Comment: @asifrc To be frank I'm not sure why you directed that comment to me. I don't disagree and have never said I do.

Comment: @Juhana, to be honest, I was reading some discussion on meta that got me all riled up and then I somewhat appended all of that to your answer without rereading it again, so my comment is somewhat directed at people who aren't even reading this lol.  Sorry for singling you out/ranting at you without true warrant :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_id='$user_id') AND (active='1' OR reserved='1')";
```

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt and concise answer.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Indaleco: hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

In maths, if you write `5 + 4 - 3`, it doesn't matter if you do the `5 + 4` part first (then `9 - 3 = 6`), or the `4 - 3` first (then `5 + 1 = 6`). However, with `AND` and `OR`, it does matter which order they are done in. So you need parentheses.

```
... WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' AND (`active`=1 OR `reserved`=1)
```

Comment: What do you mean "repwhoring"?

Comment: @tereško How exactly am I repwhoring?

Comment: the best description would seem to be: "constantly"

Comment: @tereško I still want an explanation. How can I stop allegedly repwhoring if you don't tell me what, in your opinion, I have done wrong.

Comment: @tereško there's a difference between feeding a help vampire and repwhoring. This is neither. If you're going to complain about repwhoring, please do so regarding Jon Skeet :)

Comment: +1 for a good explanation as to the need for parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation.  I haven't programmed in almost 5 years and I this was one thing that was stumping because I forgot how to do it.  I tried doing a search but alas, nothing could be found.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **All** users where Active or Reserved = 1, then simply  remove `user_id='$user_id' AND`, since the other answers will only show the single user with the a user_id of $user_id. Otherwise @Akam's got it right :)

Comment: Yes, I want to limit by the user.  This was actually a simple query to show what I wanted.  Its not the actual query I am using.

Answer (score 1):

The longer version

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND active='1' OR  user_id='$user_id' AND reserved='1'";
```

The Shorter  version

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND (active='1' OR  reserved='1')";
```

Comment: Thank you for providing both examples.